# Android - remove missed call notification

Tags: android, telephony

is there anyway to remove a missed call notification by code? And somehow remove the last missed call from call history?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, it is possible.Try this:

```
Uri UriCalls = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
Cursor cursor = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(UriCalls, null, null, null, null);
```

Reading call log entries...

```
if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER)); // for  number
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME));// for name
        String duration = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION));// for duration
        int type = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE)));// for call type, Incoming or out going
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

Deleting entry in call log...

```
String queryString= "NUMBER='" + number + "'";
if (cursor.getCount() > 0){
        getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().delete(UriCalls, queryString, null);
}
```

Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Note: Please refer this [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#NUMBER) over call log for more clearity.

Using the above code you can get the desired result.

Comment: Alright, this works, but the last incoming call from the number I want to delete gets saved. And it doesn't dissapear from the notification bar either? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)
You can clear your missed call by calling `cancel(ID)` or `calcelAll()` to clear your notifications bar.

Comment: But that is only if you develop your own notifications? I want to clear Android's notification on missed calls!

Answer (score -1):

For the part where you want to remove the last call from the log you need to move the method that is deleting the entry into a class which is a subclass of the Thread class.  This allows you to then set it to sleep for a short period to allow Android to actually write to the call log BEFORE you you run the delete query.  I had the same problem, but manage to resolve it with the code below:

```
public class DelayClearCallLog extends Thread {

    public Context context;
    public String phoneNumber;

     public DelayClearCallLog(Context ctx, String pNumber){

            context = ctx;
            phoneNumber = pNumber;
        }

     public void run() {
         try {
             sleep(2000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         clearCallLog(context, phoneNumber);
     } 
 public void clearCallLog(Context context, String phoneNumber) {
         // implement delete query here
     }
}
```

Then call the the method as follows:

```
DelayClearCallLog DelayClear = new DelayClearCallLog(context, phoneNumber);
DelayClear.start();
```