# disable missed call notification

Tags: android, notifications

i am writing an app with a BroadcastReceiver that writes notifications for each missed call. this works fine so far, but now i get two notifications for each missed call: one from my app, the other one is the standard notification.

i am interested if i can programmatically disable the system notification when i used my app so that just my own notifications are shown whenever i miss a call?

i also tried to disable the system notification in a non programmatic way, but i could not find any way how to do that.

Comment: Did you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7736613/android-remove-missed-call-notification)?

Comment: thanks, but my question was just about the notification, not about the the Calls data. i already interact with the calls and mark them as not new when i remove my self-written notification. 

the only problem is that i don't want to see the notification which android creates automatically, because then i get two with the same information each time i miss a call. but i need to write an own notification for the missed calls so that it directs the user to my address-book and its tab for the history.

Comment: Sorry, you can't prevent other apps from making notifications. What you can do is see which app does that notification and uninstall it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, thats what i already guessed, i just wanted to be sure. 

anyway i did not find any app that i can configure or even deinstall which is responsible for the notifications of the missed call. i was able to disable the sms notifications when i installed an alternative sms reader and did not want to get the sms notification twice, but i was unable do to the same concerning the missed calls.

Comment: Anything positive since then?

Comment: Stock Dialer app should have an option to disable missed call notification.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible from api 18 and up.

take a look at this link:
[Android NotificationListenerService Example](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/07/android-notificationlistenerservice.html)

you just need to ask the user to give your app permissions to in the notification access screen (in the settings).

good luck!